# Excel Count matches between 3 criteria

Tags: excel-formula

I have 2 columns of data (Names = DataA & DataB).

I have 2 variable sets of codes for which I want to count matches (Names = DataC & DataD).

DataA (Col A)

```
a
b
b
c
e
.....8000 records
```

DataB (Col B)

```
John
Fred
Gerry
Alice
etc.... 8000 records
```

DataA Variables to match a c ..... (up to 20 - RangeName=DataC)
DataB Variables to match John Fred ...  (up to 20 - RangeName=DataD)

I can count the number of matches DataA to DataC using:

```
SUMPRODUCT((DataA=DataC)*1)
```

But of I try to add the DataB to DataD criteria it doesn't work

I can do it using multiple Countifs, one for each variable in turn but with larger numbers of variables it gets very messy (example with 4 variables):

```
COUNTIFS(DataA,$U$72,dataB,AA71)+COUNTIFS(DataA,$V$72,dataB,AA71)+COUNTIFS(DataA,$W$72,dataB,AA71)+COUNTIFS(DataA,$X$72,dataB,AA71)
```

I don't want to use Pivot Tables and would like a more elegant solution - driving me nuts for 2 days now - hope it doesn't do the same for you!

Comment: What about the second sumproduct folrmula doesn't work?

Answer (score 0):

I may have misunderstood what you are trying to do but using a two criteria `SUMPRODUCT` works for me.

> =SUMPRODUCT(--(DataA=DataC),--(DataB=DataD))

Note that rather than using `*1` in the formula to have it calculate calculate the logical functions you should try to use `--` in the `SUMPRODUCT` function.